# Use compose with several functions and inner function with param

Tags: javascript, function-composition

I have the following:

```js
{
  reseller: filterOutNonUsable(dedupe(extractArrVals(data.locks.entries, 'reseller')))
}
```

What is the best way to call all these functions and use a second parameter for the extractArrVals function (see my example) so that I can use  https://www.30secondsofcode.org/snippet/compose ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));

const extractArrVals = (obj, key) => {
  /////YOUR FUNCTION
};

const dedupe = (data) => {
  /////YOUR FUNCTION
}

const filterOutNonUsable = (data) => {
  /////YOUR FUNCTION
}

// transformer or whatever it's name
const transformer = compose(
  filterOutNonUsable,
  dedupe,
  extractArrVals
);

transformer(data.locks.entries, 'reseller')
```